# confusing syntax in JSP portal

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay

JSP code in Liferay portal..

```
<portlet:actionURL name="addDetails" var="addDetailsURL" />
```

where from var  gets value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` just exposes the action URL value through a variable named `addDetailsURL`. This is so that you can use it conveniently in a link as so:

```
<a href="${addDetailsURL}">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

is used to perform any **action(Action Phase)** i.e user submitting form and **controller(processAction)** processes that request.

i.e

```
<form action="<%= addDetailsURL %>" method="POST" name="form">
// input fields which will get submitted to controller
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

from `pageContext`.

`ActionURL.toString()` is assigned to `addDetailsURL` and added to `pageContext`